# Regra para .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, htaccess

Preciso que a url final de minha página aceite **.**, **números**, **letras** e **underline** porém no formato que tenho tentado não funciona, o php me retorna no valor do parâmetro *.php* (???)

Exemplo, a url final vai ser **produto/28.01157A_2**
Qual a solução neste caso?

```
RewriteRule ^produto\/?([-\w.]+)\/?$ produto.php?referencia=$1
```

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite não precisa "escapar" o `/` com `\` (também não afeta em nada ter) neste caso especifico, a sua barra do meio nem precisa do `?` (que indica o grupo ou caractere anterior como opcional).

O problema que está retornando **.php** é justamente por causa do `?` após a barra `/`, como você "disse" pro rewrite que é opcional na primeira regra ele direciona para `/produto.php?referencia=123123`, mas ai vem o problema o valor `/produto.php` também "casa" (match) com a regex `^produto\/?([-\w.]+)\/?$`, veja um teste no regex101:

- https://regex101.com/r/VT8x3U/1

Então o que ocorre são dois redirecionamentos internos:

- Primeiro que direciona `produto/28.01157A_2` para `produto.php?referencia=28.01157A_2`
- Segundo que redireciona `produto.php?referencia=28.01157A_2` para `produto.php?referencia=.php`

Removendo o `?` já resolve:

```
RewriteRule ^produto/([-\w.]+)/?$ produto.php?referencia=$1
```

E de preferência, como você está manipulando a querystring, adicione a flag `QSA` e para evitar conflito com outras regras posteriores adicione a flag `L`

```
RewriteRule ^produto/([-\w.]+)/?$ produto.php?referencia=$1 [QSA,L]
```